# PostgreSQL currval lastval functions returning a string not a number

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to use the PostgreSQL `currval` function to retrieve a serial field which is automatically generated but I get a string instead of an int. My code is below

```
$q ="insert into       contest(name,email,cam_b,cam_e,room_num,game,amount,phone_no)values('$name','$mail','$d','$dd','o','$game','$amount','$phone')";
$q1=pg_query($q)or die(pg_last_error());
$q5="select currval('contest_no_seq')";
$v=pg_query($q5)or die(pg_last_error());
```

$v returns Resource id #5 instead of an int value and i cant seem to use the strpos function to get the position of #

```
$er=strpos($v,'d');
if($er===false)
echo "not";
else
echo "$er -";
```

I am using PostgreSQL on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly is being returned but it is better to return the sequence value in the `insert` command:

```
$q = "
    insert into contest (
      name, email,cam_b, cam_e, room_num, game, amount, phone_no
    ) values (
    '$name','$mail','$d','$dd','o','$game','$amount','$phone'
    ) returning id
";
```

`returning id` above is the sequence column.